# Boostrap 3 - Align cards

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I´m trying to create a view with multiple cards and map. I need to alignment all elements. I don´t know exactly can i do this, the map 'brokes' all alignment.

The code is

```
   <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-8">
              <div class="info-box">
                <span class="info-box-icon bg-green"><i class="fa fa-tint"></i></span>
                <div class="info-box-content">
                  <span class="info-box-text">Último valor ({{ultimoValor ? ultimoValor['timestamp'] :''}})</span>
                  <span class="info-box-number">{{ultimoValor ? ultimoValor['value'] :''}}m³</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <agm-map [fitBounds]="true" [streetViewControl]="true" [fullscreenControl]="false">
                <agm-marker [agmFitBounds]="true" [latitude]="latitud" [longitude]="longitud">
                </agm-marker>
              </agm-map>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="info-box">
                  <span class="info-box-icon bg-aqua"><i class="fa fa-divide"></i></span>
                  <div class="info-box-content">
                    <span class="info-box-text">Media diaria</span>
                    <span class="info-box-number">{{consumoMediaDiaria?consumoMediaDiaria['value']:''}}m³</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="info-box">
                  <span class="info-box-icon bg-aqua"><i class="fa fa-divide"></i></span>
                  <div class="info-box-content">
                    <span class="info-box-text">Consumo media
                      mes </span>
                    <span class="info-box-number">{{consumoMediaMensual?consumoMediaMensual['value']:''}}m³
                    </span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 pointer">
              <div class="info-box">
                <span class="info-box-icon bg-yellow"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
                <div class="info-box-content">
                  <span class="info-box-text">Valor cierre mes
                  </span>
                  <span class="info-box-number">{{ultimoValorCierre? ultimoValorCierre['value']:''}}m³</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 pointer">
              <div class="info-box">
                <span class="info-box-icon bg-yellow"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
                <div class="info-box-content">
                  <span class="info-box-text">Consumo último mes
                  </span>
                  <span class="info-box-number">
                    {{consumoUltimoMes ? consumoUltimoMes['value']:''}}m³
                  </span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="col-md-6 pointer">
                <div (click)="showAlerts()" class=" info-box">
                  <span class="info-box-icon bg-red"><i class=" fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i></span>
                  <div class="info-box-content">
                    <span class="info-box-text">Alertas última semana</span>
                    <span class="info-box-number">
                      {{ultimasAlarmasActivas?.length}}
                    </span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div (click)="showAlerts()" class="info-box pointer">
                  <span [ngClass]="alerts?.length ? 'info-box-icon bg-red icon-alt': 'info-box-icon bg-red'"><i
                      class=" fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i></span>
                  <div class="info-box-content">
                    <span *ngIf="alerts?.length>0" class="info-box-number">Alertas <b>({{alerts.length}})</b></span>
                    <span *ngIf="alerts?.length==0" class="info-box-text">Alertas
                    </span>
                    <ol *ngIf="alerts?.length>0">
                      <li *ngFor="let alert of alerts | slice:0:5">
                        <div>{{alert.nombre}} </div>
                      </li>
                    </ol>
                    <span *ngIf="alerts?.length==0" class="info-box-number">
                      {{alerts.length}}
                    </span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

And here we have a screen of 'error'.

[image]

As we can see the cards has a blank space after first element, then is the map and finally are all the rest of cards. I need to remove this blank space and align all elements.

Comment: Add <div class="row"> after every row.

Comment: Why you not use latest Bootstrap 4 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need class 'row' to get the effect that you're looking for - check the code below which has extra borders for internal/external boxes so that you can identify what is going on and make changes accordingly

working **snippet on Bootstrap v3 below**:

```css
.info-box {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.top-level {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class='row'>
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12 top-level">
      <div class='row'>
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <div class="info-box">
            <span class="info-box-icon bg-green"><i class="fa fa-tint"></i></span>
            <div class="info-box-content">
              <span class="info-box-text">Último valor
                                    ({{ultimoValor ? ultimoValor['timestamp'] :''}})</span>
              <span class="info-box-number">{{ultimoValor ? ultimoValor['value'] :''}}m³</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='row'>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <div class="info-box">
            <span class="info-box-icon bg-aqua"><i class="fa fa-divide"></i></span>
            <div class="info-box-content">
              <span class="info-box-text">Media diaria</span>
              <span class="info-box-number">{{consumoMediaDiaria?consumoMediaDiaria['value']:''}}m³</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <div class="info-box">
            <span class="info-box-icon bg-aqua"><i class="fa fa-divide"></i></span>
            <div class="info-box-content">
              <span class="info-box-text">Consumo media
                                    mes </span>
              <span class="info-box-number">{{consumoMediaMensual?consumoMediaMensual['value']:''}}m³
                                </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 pointer">
          <div class="info-box">
            <span class="info-box-icon bg-yellow"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
            <div class="info-box-content">
              <span class="info-box-text">Valor cierre mes
                                </span>
              <span class="info-box-number">{{ultimoValorCierre? ultimoValorCierre['value']:''}}m³</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 pointer">
          <div class="info-box">
            <span class="info-box-icon bg-yellow"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
            <div class="info-box-content">
              <span class="info-box-text">Consumo último mes
                                </span>
              <span class="info-box-number">
                                    {{consumoUltimoMes ? consumoUltimoMes['value']:''}}m³
                                </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 top-level">
      <agm-map [fitBounds]="true" [streetViewControl]="true" [fullscreenControl]="false">
        <agm-marker [agmFitBounds]="true" [latitude]="latitud" [longitude]="longitud">
        </agm-marker>
      </agm-map>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>


<div class="container">
  <div class='row'>
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 top-level">
      <!-- another-->
      <div class='row'>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 pointer">
          <div (click)="showAlerts()" class=" info-box">
            <span class="info-box-icon bg-red"><i class=" fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i></span>
            <div class="info-box-content">
              <span class="info-box-text">Alertas última semana</span>
              <span class="info-box-number">
                                    {{ultimasAlarmasActivas?.length}}
                                </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 pointer">
          <div (click)="showAlerts()" class="info-box ">
            <span [ngClass]="alerts?.length ? 'info-box-icon bg-red icon-alt': 'info-box-icon bg-red'"><i
                                    class=" fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i></span>
            <div class="info-box-content">
              <span *ngIf="alerts?.length>0" class="info-box-number">Alertas
                                    <b>({{alerts.length}})</b></span>
              <span *ngIf="alerts?.length==0" class="info-box-text">Alertas
                                </span>
              <ol *ngIf="alerts?.length>0">
                <li *ngFor="let alert of alerts | slice:0:5">
                  <div>{{alert.nombre}} </div>
                </li>
              </ol>
              <span *ngIf="alerts?.length==0" class="info-box-number">
                                    {{alerts.length}}
                                </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

working **snippet on Bootstrap v4 below**:

```css
.info-box {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.top-level {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class='row'>
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-12 top-level">
      <div class='row'>
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
          <div class="info-box">
            <span class="info-box-icon bg-green"><i class="fa fa-tint"></i></span>
            <div class="info-box-content">
              <span class="info-box-text">Último valor
                                    ({{ultimoValor ? ultimoValor['timestamp'] :''}})</span>
              <span class="info-box-number">{{ultimoValor ? ultimoValor['value'] :''}}m³</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='row'>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-12">
          <div class="info-box">
            <span class="info-box-icon bg-aqua"><i class="fa fa-divide"></i></span>
            <div class="info-box-content">
              <span class="info-box-text">Media diaria</span>
              <span class="info-box-number">{{consumoMediaDiaria?consumoMediaDiaria['value']:''}}m³</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-12">
          <div class="info-box">
            <span class="info-box-icon bg-aqua"><i class="fa fa-divide"></i></span>
            <div class="info-box-content">
              <span class="info-box-text">Consumo media
                                    mes </span>
              <span class="info-box-number">{{consumoMediaMensual?consumoMediaMensual['value']:''}}m³
                                </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-12 pointer">
          <div class="info-box">
            <span class="info-box-icon bg-yellow"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
            <div class="info-box-content">
              <span class="info-box-text">Valor cierre mes
                                </span>
              <span class="info-box-number">{{ultimoValorCierre? ultimoValorCierre['value']:''}}m³</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-12 pointer">
          <div class="info-box">
            <span class="info-box-icon bg-yellow"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
            <div class="info-box-content">
              <span class="info-box-text">Consumo último mes
                                </span>
              <span class="info-box-number">
                                    {{consumoUltimoMes ? consumoUltimoMes['value']:''}}m³
                                </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-12 top-level">
      <agm-map [fitBounds]="true" [streetViewControl]="true" [fullscreenControl]="false">
        <agm-marker [agmFitBounds]="true" [latitude]="latitud" [longitude]="longitud">
        </agm-marker>
      </agm-map>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>


<div class="container">
  <div class='row'>
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 top-level">
      <!-- another-->
      <div class='row'>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-12 pointer">
          <div (click)="showAlerts()" class=" info-box">
            <span class="info-box-icon bg-red"><i class=" fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i></span>
            <div class="info-box-content">
              <span class="info-box-text">Alertas última semana</span>
              <span class="info-box-number">
                                    {{ultimasAlarmasActivas?.length}}
                                </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-12 pointer">
          <div (click)="showAlerts()" class="info-box ">
            <span [ngClass]="alerts?.length ? 'info-box-icon bg-red icon-alt': 'info-box-icon bg-red'"><i
                                    class=" fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i></span>
            <div class="info-box-content">
              <span *ngIf="alerts?.length>0" class="info-box-number">Alertas
                                    <b>({{alerts.length}})</b></span>
              <span *ngIf="alerts?.length==0" class="info-box-text">Alertas
                                </span>
              <ol *ngIf="alerts?.length>0">
                <li *ngFor="let alert of alerts | slice:0:5">
                  <div>{{alert.nombre}} </div>
                </li>
              </ol>
              <span *ngIf="alerts?.length==0" class="info-box-number">
                                    {{alerts.length}}
                                </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing div-row

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
     Your content in col-8
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
     Your content in col-4
    </div>
   </div><!-- .row -->
  </div><!-- .col-md-12 -->
 </div><!-- .row -->
</div><!-- .container -->
```